# Scrollyfy effect in twitterbootstrap template

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The template in this [Link](http://www.dotrex.co/vertica/themes/melissa.html#) contain a nice scroll effect, when  someone slide down/move down then the pipe-line with circle fill, I don't know what exactly this effect is can some one guide me that what is this effect actually, or how to get it?

Comment: What would you try before?

Comment: it's a prallax scroll. Look it up on google and if you have specific questions, come back and ask

Comment: actually i can't understand it properly, that what is going in  this templete, and i try simple step,s, i also try to cop the same css in this templete but still not getting this,,,,,

Comment: Mike Dinescu, i know but how to get excatly the same effect..

Comment: @webydesigny, if **you know** then why didn't you ask that? And where are you stuck? Either edit your question or ask a new one.

Comment: Mike Dinescu, please read my previous comment, i can,t understand the css effect use in this templete, and please provide a solution insted of chat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use photoshop or some graphic program to create images you want and then arrange it with css, this is all you need to get the same effect.